# Reply from the address to which it was sent - AWS WORKMAIL

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-workmail

I am testing a workmail service but there are very few settings as for a paid service.

How can I set up to automatically reply from the given email address to which the email was sent? I have added alias to my account like contact@domain1 and contact@domain2 etc.

When somebody sends a message to this alias(contact@domain2), reply is sent from the main address (like admin@mymaindomain). **How can I make it to automatically reply from the alias to which the message was sent?**

Comment: You might have better luck getting a proper answer for this at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ since Amazon Workmail is a webmail application like gmail. Though — from what I've found — what you want doesn't seem possible yet.

Comment: @Ali agreed. I put a bounty up (definitely should have thought to migrate it first) just in case someone figured a way. But I don't think it's possible yet either. I've submitted a ticket to Amazon since their docs make it sound like this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For auto-reply from the given email address to which the email was sent:

- delete the alias `contact@domain2`
- create real e-mail address `contact@domain2`
- forward all e-mails from `contact@domain2` to `admin@mymaindomain`
- define auto-response for `contact@domain2`

analog for `contact@domain1`

Comment: "create real e-mail address" — Does this mean that a new user has to be created? Doesn't this increase the cost since Amazon WorkMail costs $4 per user per month?